# How to delete documents from Filetable?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, filetable

I am trying to delete some documents from sql server's filetable.

Here I have one table in which I am storing all my Attachment's details and Documents in sql server's file table named Attchemnts.

AttachmentDetails table has below schema,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AttachmentDetails](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [DocumentName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DocumentType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ModifiedDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NULL,
    )
```

Whenever I am uploading any document to File table then I am inserting that document's detailed information in AttchemntsDetails table as per table schema.

Here I have tried the below solution

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteFiles] 
AS
BEGIN
DELETE Attachments
FROM AttachmentDetails a
WHERE 
    DocumentType = 'video/mp4'  AND  DATEDIFF(day, a.CreatedDateTime, GETDATE())<11
end
```

This procedure suppose to delete only Video/mp4 files who are 10 days older But it deletes any type of document from the filetable.

Comment: `DELETE ... FROM ... WHERE ...` The storage type doesn't matter

Comment: The query posted here would result in *random deletions* because there's *no* guarantee what all those `TOP 1` queries will return when there's no ORDER BY clause. What are you trying to do? It's a lot easier to write a proper `DELETE` query than this complicated loop.

Comment: I wrote loop cause there i awant to check that condition for each record in the table.

Comment: That's what the `WHERE` clause in all queries is for. `WHERE 
    DocumentType = 'video/mp4' AND
    CreatedDateTime < DATEADD(day,30,getdate())` checks all records for both conditions and only deletes those that match

Comment: BTW post the table schemas, a sample of the data and the desired output. Right now people have to *guess* what those tables are. Is `ID` a primary key in both table's? What is `Table1`?

Answer (score 1):

SQL is a set-based language. For every cursor/loop based script there's a far simpler and faster set based solution. In any case, the way this query is written would result in random deletions since there's no guarantee what all those `TOP 1` queries will return without an `ORDER BY` clause.

It looks like you're trying to delete all video attachments older than 30 days. It also looks like the date is stored in a separate table called `table1`. You can write a `DELETE` statement whose rows come from a JOIN if you use the `FROM` clause, eg:

```
DELETE Attachments
FROM Attachments inner join table1 a on a.ID=Attachments.ID
WHERE 
    DocumentType = 'video/mp4' AND
    CreatedDateTime < DATEADD(day,-30,getdate())
```

**EDIT**

The original query contained `DATEADD(day,30,getdate())` when it should be `DATEADD(day,-30,getdate())`

**Example**

Assuming we have those two tables :

```
create table attachments (ID int primary key,DocumentType nvarchar(100))

insert into attachments (ID,DocumentType)
values
(1,'video/mp4'),
(2,'audio/mp3'),
(3,'application/octet-stream'),
(4,'video/mp4')
```

and

```
create table table1 (ID int primary key, CreatedDateTime datetime)

insert into table1 (ID,CreatedDateTime)
values
(1,dateadd(day,-40,getdate())),
(2,dateadd(day,-40,getdate())),
(3,getdate()),
(4,getdate())
```

Executing the `DELETE` query will only delete the Attachment with ID=1. The query

````
select *
from Attachments
```

Will return :

```
ID  DocumentType
2   audio/mp3
3   application/octet-stream
4   video/mp4
```
````

Comment: I tried above query and that have deleted all the documents from the filetable.

Comment: That would happen if *all* of them matched the criteria. If all attachments are videos older than 30 days, they'll be deleted. On the other hand, if the `ID` columns are misused and eg `table1.ID` is *not* unique, perhaps there's a matching `table1` record for every attachment. You didnt' provide any information about the tables, only an invalid query

Comment: Actualy there were only 2-3 documents of type video rest of them were images, text and  doc files.
yeah I agree that i haven't provided table schema.

Comment: Oops, it should be `-30`, not `30`